# pending slurm jobs not showing up in sacct

Tags: linux, slurm

I am experiencing an issue with `slurm` where `sacct` does not show pending jobs.  Below, you can see that job `110061` doesn't show up in `sacct` but is clearly pending in `squeue`.  Any ideas as to why this would happen?

```
[plcmp14evs:/sim/dev/ash/projects/full-trees] 153% sacct -j 110061
       JobID    JobName  Partition    Account  AllocCPUS      State ExitCode
------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------
[plcmp14evs:/sim/dev/ash/projects/full-trees] 154% squeue -j 110061
  JOBID PARTITION    STATE     USER       TIME TIMELIMIT  NODES NODELIST(REASON) NAME
 110061  eventual  PENDING    andrew      0:00 UNLIMITED      1   (Priority)    [rf] script.8.R
```

-- Edit --

This is the output of `scontrol show config | grep Acc`

```
AccountingStorageBackupHost = (null)
AccountingStorageEnforce = none
AccountingStorageHost   = localhost
AccountingStorageLoc    = /disks/linux/tmp/slurm_accounting.txt
AccountingStoragePort   = 0
AccountingStorageType   = accounting_storage/filetxt
AccountingStorageUser   = root
AccountingStoreJobComment = YES
JobAcctGatherFrequency  = 3 sec
JobAcctGatherType       = jobacct_gather/linux
```

Comment: Are you sure accounting is enabled? What does `scontrol show config` say about `AccountingStorageType` ?

Comment: Yes accounting is definitely enabled, it seems to work fine for all jobs except those in a pending state. Updated post with some scontrol output.

Comment: Do the job suddenly appear then when they start running or when they finish? -- Also is sacct not an alias with filtering options to sacct?  (Trying to exclude a maximum of options..)

Comment: The jobs suddenly appear as soon as they start running.  And sacct is just the plain old sacct command-line tool, not aliased.

Comment: However, once they are running it seems like it won't update again until the next change in state because sacct always says the elapsed time is 00:00:00 while running, but the upon completion/failure sacct while have the correct elapsed time.  Although, if the job goes from running to suspended, the elapsed time is still 00:00:00.

Comment: what is the value of `JobAcctGatherFrequency` ?

Comment: JobAcctGatherFrequency is 3 sec

Comment: I have the same problem but only with jobs with dependencies.... was this issue solved?

Answer (score -1):

At this point there is nothing to record, since the job has not even started yet.